# The only thing I can do on my iPhone 6 is make calls

Tags: iphone, ios

Today I was in a bike accident. I landed right on my phone (which was in my pocket) and cracked the entire screen. I've even got a bruise on my leg where the phone was sitting.
Anyways, I texted a few people and got back home. Fast forward an hour, I lose internet connection.
My phone still has 3 bars of LTE, it still has 3 bars of wifi, yet I cannot do a single thing on it. I can't load my email, I can't browse safari, I can't get on reddit, etc.. The only thing I can do is make calls.
I've reset my network settings, I've restarted my phone 3 times, and I've done all the basic "turn it off and back on again"

It is an iPhone 6+, iOS 11.0

Does anyone know what could have happened to it or any fixes?

Comment: It is broken because you fell on it and it needs to be fixed. I don't think anybody at this site can fix it for you, or tell you its _not_ broken. Sorry about your fall, though. I hope you're OK and I assume you were wearing a helmet. If you were _not_ wearing a helmet, get one before you fix your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot visually inspect the damage on your phone, I would say take your phone to the Apple Store to get a better answer. The Apple Store will also suggest how much it would cost to repair the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a full restore via iTunes. But more than likely the device should be replaced.